# How can I convert PHASset UTI to string with mime type in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mime-types

Objective C

```
 NSString* mimeType = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass
                                ((__bridge CFStringRef)assetInfo.dataUTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
```

assetInfo.dataUTI // UTI getting from requestImage data from PHAsset.

Comment: Where is your Swift code attempt ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have created mimeType from UTI

```
let mimeType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(dataUTI! as CFString, kUTTagClassMIMEType as CFString)?.takeRetainedValue() as String?
```